# HTML-CSS- Table rows not working as expected

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```css
.MainTable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.SecondRow {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.TopRow {
  background-color: green;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="MainTable">
  <tr class="TopRow">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="SecondRow">
    <td class="Tags"></td>

    <td>
      <table class="ContentTable">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td class="Stats"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see the second row is not extending to its full extent. And why are the tds not equally spaced?
I want the second row to occupy the full width and 100% height too. But as you can see, only some of it is showing. The second row is not occupying the full width and height. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are `5` `<td>` in first row where as there are `3` `<td>` in second row!

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal So..? Is there any way to stop the inheritance?

Comment: Yes you can do it, what is the ratio of width you need for the second one?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal, The second td needs to occupy 50% and the other two 25 25
,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `colspan="2"` attribute on the `<td>`

```css
.MainTable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.SecondRow {
  background-color: blue;
  height: calc(100vh - 25px);
  width: 100%;
}

.TopRow {
  background-color: green;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="MainTable">
  <tr class="TopRow">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="SecondRow">
    <td class="Tags" colspan="3"></td>

    <td colspan="1">
      <table class="ContentTable">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td class="Stats"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But the height is not  100% in the second row? any idea on what to do on it?

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta You have asigned the `height: 25px;` to `TopRow` but not on `SecondRow`. I have added it.

Comment: I want the second row to extend to the full screen downwards. Maximum.

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta I did it 

Comment: that's cheeky solution. Isn't there a more "smoother solution", like height:100%?

Comment: @VishwaMithraTatta Not in this situation 